# Is is possible to bind my own closures and variables to groovlet?

Tags: groovy, groovlet

There are some variables and closures in `groovlet` like request, response, out, forward, redirect...

Is it possible to bind my own variables and closures to `groovlet` automatically?

I want this feature for `${escapeHtml(params.value)}` like things.

Answer (score 3):

`GroovyServlet` provides a hook for doing exactly this: [`setVariables`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/servlet/AbstractHttpServlet.html#setVariables%28groovy.servlet.ServletBinding%29).  Create a subclass of `GroovyServlet` that overrides this method and populate the `ServletBinding` with whatever you want.